How to decompile android13 vdex files？
VdexExtractor only supports vdex compilation for Android 10. How can I decompile higher versions of vdex files?
$./run.sh -i boot-framework.vdex -o ./out
[INFO]: Processing 1 input Vdex files
[WARN]: Skipping 'boot-framework' since no decompiled resources found
[INFO]: 0 binaries have been successfully deodexed

Are there any other tools available for decompiling vdex file？
